# Submit data to Mysql without a form through php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a C# program that needs to pass specific values to our remote server nightly.

I already have a database "counter" with just a few tables: ClientID, ClientName, BoxesMoved, and ReportDate.

I need to pass the values through a simple post command WITHOUT THE USE OF A FORM, but things aren't working properly. Here's what I was starting with.

I was trying to pass the values like this: ( **test.php?clientid=01?clientname=theclient?boxesmoved=185443?reportdate=07-17-2015**) but you more experienced developers know, this didn't work.  Is this possible, and where can I find any information to aid me in my process.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root";   // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="counter"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="boxcounter"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$clientid=$_POST['ClientID'];
$clientname=$_POST['ClientName'];
$boxesmoved=$_POST['BoxesMoved'];
$reportdate=$_POST['ReportDate'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(reportdate, clientid, boxesmoved, clientname)VALUES('$ClientID', '$ClientName', '$BoxesMoved', '$ReportDate', )";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: if you're passing data through URI try `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: In addition, the calling URL should be `test.php?clientid=01&clientname=theclient&boxesmoved=185443&reportdate=07-17-2015` (all question marks after the first changed to ampersands).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the variables in $_POST but should be looking at $_GET if you are passing them through the URL like that.

Also, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated, and the way you are using them opens you up to SQL injection.